# Windows Mapped Network Drive Does not show linux dotfiles

Tags: windows-10, citrix, citrix-receiver

I connect to a [VDI](https://www.citrix.com/glossary/vdi.html) machine via [Citrix](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/). This is a dedicated VDI.
I connect on my physical Mac Machine running MacOs 10.14.4

The VDI machine is running windows 10 and it automatically has my Host machine drive mapped (The Mac drive).

In the Windows VDI, I navigate to a folder on the mapped network drive (Mac) but it does not show any file/folder that starts with `.` such as `.git` folder or `.content.xml` file.

Presumably because `dotfiles` are treated as hidden and MacOs does not report them to windows?

I have tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) and [this](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/jsi-tip-3109-how-do-i-get-dir-command-show-system-and-hidden-files)

I have also naviaged to the directory in CMD and tried `dir /ah` and same result, no `dotfiles` show.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I have tested accessing the same VDI but from a windows machine instead of a mac machine. It works just fine and the mapped drive does show the dotfiles. It seems only macs are impacted by this issue.

Comment: Samba has an "hide dot files = no" option, but you are probably not using Samba? Are you using `dir` (or Explorer) and does `dir /ah` show the dotfiles?

Comment: I am not using samba. The VDI maps the local Mac drive as a windows network drive.

Comment: And my second question?

Comment: Yes, I used the /ah flags, same result, unfortunately.

Comment: what happens if you create a directory starting with a *dot* on the share?

Comment: Which software do you use to go into the VDI machine? SSH, remote desktop?

Comment: In addition: I have seen several times users in your situation that have created symlinks to dotfiles/folders. I wonder if that's not the solution when your OS refuses to externally list such files.

Comment: @harrymc adding a dotfile folder on windows creates the folder but I cannot open it, and on refresh, the folder no longer appears. As I indicated, I login via Citrix. Creating symlinks works, but is not feasible because I have many many dotfiles that get created/removed and some that are not managed by me. Also, it is important to keep dotfile names as they are and not change them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dir /ah` has not shown the dotfiles, it is clear that MacOs does not publish
these files when externalizing the folder.

I don't have a Mac, but from published data it seems that there is no parameter
for including dotfiles (or perhaps hidden files).
Search your software for such an option.

If no such option exists, perhaps the solution will be to create symlinks to
these dotfiles or folders, stored inside the mapped folder, whose names will not
start with a dot.
I have seen several times users in your situation that have created such symlinks,
probably for the same reason.
You will just have to experiment.

Comment: You have indicated that you have too many dotfiles for symlinks to be a solution. The problem is on the Mac side in the software that you use. I suggest that you ask Citrix Support if they have a parameter for passing dotfiles, and if this doesn't exist then there is no solution except using another software, which might be impractical for you.

Comment: According to the last entry in [this thread](https://community.sharefilesupport.com/citrixsharefile/topics/shared_folder_hierarchy_not_replicated_to_local_pc?topic-reply-list[settings][page]=2#topic-reply-list), the file/folder should be designated for 'Offline Access' (aka Sync), but I don't know if Citrix Files is your product.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My product is citrix-reciever and not citrix sharefile. I am trying to reach citrix support to see if there is any configuration that can be done on their side. Will keep this thread updated.

Comment: You might also post a question in the [Citrix Discussions Forums](https://discussions.citrix.com/).

Comment: I’ll try that, tanks!